# Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: typescript

```
const initialState =  {
    id: 0,
    studentId : 0,
    targets : []
}

const [program, setProgram] = useState(initialState);
```

In a function I am doing below
setProgram({...program,studentId= selectedStudent?.id})

selected Student is defined as below:
selectedStudent: Student | undefined;

I do not want to change selectedStudent: Student | undefined;

What can I do in initialState to get rid of the error

Comment: `setProgram({ ...program, studentId = selectedStudent?.id ?? 0 })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've implicitly defined the `studentId` property as holding a number.

`selectedStudent?.id` might be a number or might be `undefined`.

Since `undefined` isn't a number, you get an error.

There are a couple of things you *could* do to get rid of the error, but it isn't possible to tell what the *right* thing to do is based on the information you've provided.

**Test if the value is `undefined` and provide a default number**

```js
setProgram({
    ...program,
    studentId: selectedStudent?.id ?? 0
});
```

**Or use an explicit type which allows the property to be undefined**

```js
type Program = {
    id: number;
    studentId?: number;
    targets: Something[]
}

const initialState: Program =  {
    id: 0,
    studentId : 0,
    targets : []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to handle it on the state side of things.

It is inferred from your `initialState`, that `studentId` is a number, and since `undefined` is not a number your `selectedStudent?.id` assignment triggers the error.

If you want to assign `0` when the `selectedStudent` is `undefined` then just provide this alternative

```
setProgram({...program,studentId= selectedStudent?.id ?? 0})
```

You could however tell typescript what are the accepted values for `studentId` with

```
type StateType = {
    id: number,
    studentId?: number, // or number | undefined
    targets: string[] // assuming string array
}
const initialState: StateType =  {
    id: 0,
    studentId : 0,
    targets : []
}
```

or even

```
const initialState =  {
    id: 0,
    studentId : 0 as number | undefined,
    targets : []
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
const initialState : any =  {
    id: 0,
    studentId : 0,
    targets : []
}

const [program, setProgram] = useState(initialState);
```

will work.

Comment: Using `any` is essentially not using TypeScript. It's a cheap and nasty hack that will come back to bite you.

Comment: yeah i know its a cheat